# Rmagic Anaconda Jupyter

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

I was trying to embed some r code on a python 2.7 kernel notebook but it doesn't work.

I'm using Anaconda's Jupyter so i've tried :

```
conda install rpy2
```

or

```
conda install rpy2.ipython
```

Unfortunately anytime I try to use %%R or %R nothing happens except the error message that states that there's no %R magic.

In fact as I try:

```
%lsmagic
```

a whole bunch of magic appears except R.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found!

rpy2 package has been moved to rpy2.ipython

therefore to use %%R you must first call

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

instead of

```
%load_ext rmagic
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming R is installed, make sure to [load the magic](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/config/extensions/rmagic.html) before using it:

```
%load_ext rmagic
```

Comment: It is but it still doesn't work. I usually call %load_ext magic in a top cell where i also call all python modules i need.